# validation login with data stored on localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, local-storage

the code i made only reads the last index from localStorage for login validation, can someone help to login using all existing data?

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function(){
        var usernamelogin = $('#usernamelogin').val()
        var passwordlogin = $('#passwordlogin').val()
        var data_user1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data_user'))
        
        for(var i in data_user1){
        var entry = data_user1[i]
        }
        
        if(usernamelogin == entry.username && passwordlogin == entry.password){
            alert("Log in successfull")
            window.location.href = "curhat.jsp"
        }else{
            alert("wrong username or password")
            }           
        //console.log(data_user1)
        //console.log('username = ' + entry.username)
        
    })
```

Comment: Move the `if` statement inside the `for` loop. Also note that using localStorage to store log in credentials is incredibly insecure - I assume this is just a test project?

Comment: ya just a test project. i was move if statement inside for loop, but the data will loop repeatedly to read all index data (example: there are 7 index data, then the alert notification will come out 7 times before moving to the next page).

Comment: That's true, which is why you need to not use `alert()` for user feedback, show a message to the user in the HTML after the loop completes with no matches. It's best to avoid `alert()` for everything, to be honest, as it's not a good experience for the user.

Comment: thank you sir, finally i can solve this problem